# using android TextToSpeech feature with a pdf file

Tags: java, android, pdf, text-to-speech, google-text-to-speech

Android provides as with a feature called TextToSpeech with is capable of speaking the text aloud using this code i can make any sentence to be heard aloud in android .

```
TextToSpeech tts= new TextToSpeech(this, this);
int result = tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
tts.speak(**text**, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
```

Here the `text` variable stores the sentence to be heard but my problem is that i don't want just a variable there what i want is to place an entire pdf or .doc file over there.So that when i click on play button it starts reading the current pdf or (any extension) file aloud with android `TextToSpeech` feature . any tutorial with pdf reading capability would help me alot.Thanks

Comment: Use either iText or PDFBox.  They are the two main libraries for reading pdf files in Java

Comment: @demongolem can you provide me with some examples ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, from PDFBox.  Example taken from [here](http://www.printmyfolders.com/Home/PDFBox-Tutorial)

```
import java.io.*;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.*;
import org.apache.pdfbox.util.*;

public class PDFTest {

 public static void main(String[] args){
 PDDocument pd;
 BufferedWriter wr;
 try {
         File input = new File("C:\\Invoice.pdf");  // The PDF file from where you would like to extract
         File output = new File("C:\\SampleText.txt"); // The text file where you are going to store the extracted data
         pd = PDDocument.load(input);
         System.out.println(pd.getNumberOfPages());
         System.out.println(pd.isEncrypted());
         pd.save("CopyOfInvoice.pdf"); // Creates a copy called "CopyOfInvoice.pdf"
         PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper();
         stripper.setStartPage(3); //Start extracting from page 3
         stripper.setEndPage(5); //Extract till page 5
         wr = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(output)));
         stripper.writeText(pd, wr);
         if (pd != null) {
             pd.close();
         }
        // I use close() to flush the stream.
        wr.close();
 } catch (Exception e){
         e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }
}
```

PDFStripper is the key here.  That extracts the text from the PDF.